# NEST Returns Nothing on Fuzzy Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I use the following query in Sense and I get some results back:

```
POST myindex/mytype/_search
{
  "query": {
        "fuzzy_like_this_field" : {
            "BookLabel" : {
                "like_text" : "myBook",
                "max_query_terms" : 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with the following code using Nest I get nothing:

```
    var docs = client.Search<dynamic>(b => b
            .Index("myindex")
            .Type("mytype")
                .Query(q => q
                    .Fuzzy(fz => fz
                        .OnField("BookLabel")
                        .Value("myBook")
                    )
                )
        ).Documents.ToList();
```

I can't see the difference between them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You NEST query you have above produces the following query DSL

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "BookLabel": {
        "value": "myBook"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get the nearest equivalent to a `fuzzy_like_this_field` query (**[which is deprecated in Elasticsearch 1.6.0 and will be removed in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-field-query.html)**), you can run a `fuzzy_like_this` query only on the field you're interested in

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connection = new InMemoryConnection(settings);
    var client = new ElasticClient(connection: connection);

    var docs = client.Search<dynamic>(b => b
        .Index("myindex")
        .Type("mytype")
        .Query(q => q
            .FuzzyLikeThis(fz => fz
                .LikeText("myBook")
                .MaxQueryTerms(12)
                .OnFields(new [] { "BookLabel" })                           
            )
        )
    );

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(docs.RequestInformation.Request));
}
```

This outputs the following query DSL

```
{
  "query": {
    "flt": {
      "fields": [
        "BookLabel"
      ],
      "like_text": "myBook",
      "max_query_terms": 12
    }
  }
}
```

which should yield the same results as you see in Sense.

Comment: Thanks Russ. I also noticed the previous generated DSL wasn't correct. Since flt will be deprecated what should I use instead?